# Drool implementation running out of memory using stateful sessions

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am trying to resurrect a project that I did not write that implements the Drool engine. There is close to no documentation to go off of, and I've personally never used Drools in any of my previous projects. I am still doing research on Kie / Drools to wrap my head around this but in the mean time, I am hoping someone can shortcut me to a solution.

This project contains somewhere in the realm of 200-300 rules which implement various conditional constructs. I don't believe the issue lies within the rules (though I could be wrong since there plenty of rules using regular expression) but rather within the `StatefulKnowledgeSession` implementation.

I think it is worth noting that:

- The drool engine framework functions for several minutes before it is no longer capable of producing any results
- It starts to slow down significantly before it can't produce any results
- The stream that this application interacts with is considered "big data"
- There is another thread polling every 1000 seconds for results (I would prefer to setup a listener rather than to poll for results)
- The application creates several KieSessions operating on different threads

I ran a profiler on the JVM and it quickly exposed exactly where my heap is filling up:

**Method profiler:**
[image: expireRightTuple method]
**Object profiler:**
[image: RightTupleImpl objects]

I can try to provide as much code as possible, though being new to this rule framework I'm unsure where to begin.

Comment: Why must it be stateful?  I would think a rules engine should be idempotent.  Stateful can't scale.

Comment: @duffymo I am still trying to figure this out. There are some rules that rely on other rules to generate a result, which requires a stateful session. But there aren't many that I would think result in the issues that are occurring.

Comment: I'm thinking about it from the point of view of the user, not the rules engine.  Rete forward/back induction ought to allow you you iterate through a rules set to a converged solution.  Once you converge memory should be cleaned up after the response is sent.  Perhaps you need to profile your solution to see where memory is being consumed.

Comment: @duffymo Unless I don't understand your statement, the second image is a memory profiler. I'm restricted to what I can discuss in regards to the project which makes it difficult for you, and anyone else reading my question to understand the fundamental problems of this project.

Comment: No, my apologies.  You understand just fine.  I misread your post - thought it was a stack trace, not a memory profile.  My mistake.